# TortoiseGit - No option for Post-Commit Hook in the Settings

Tags: git, githooks, tortoisegit

I am trying to setup post-commit hook in TortoiseGit settings. But I cannot find
this option. Here is the screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

TortoiseGit Settings for Hook. I am using:

```
TortoiseGit 1.8.14.0 (C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin)
```

How do I set post-commit hook?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from TortoiseGit 2.3.1 there is support for pre-rebase hook and starting with 2.5.5 also for the post-commit hook.

The hooks can be configured using TortoiseGit settings: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks

Comment: Preview releases are available here: https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/previews/

Comment: Upgraded Tortoise to the latest and the hook was found.